# How to log a JavaScript variable's value without console.log()?

Tags: javascript, variables, console, data-analysis, console.log

In R, you can assign a variable then print it to the console simply by typing the variable. For example:

R code:

```
a <- "Sample string"

a
```

Output:

```
Sample string
```

I'd like to do something similar with the JavaScript console but without writing `console.log()` all the time. For example:

JavaScript code:

```
var a = "Sample string";

a 

//or a; is fine to prevent an error
```

Desirable Output:

```
Sample string
```

Edit:

To clarify, I'm not entering the variable into the console directly. I'm using a webpage editor. This is a very simplified version:

```
<textbox id="ta">
    var a = "Sample string";
    a 
</textbox>

<script>
    var myText = document.getElementById("ta").value;
    console.log(eval(myText)); //ideally, this will show the value of a
</script>
```

Comment: I think most REPL do this (browser consoles, node REPL, online versions, ...)

Comment: @ASDFGerte I get an Invalid regular expression: missing / at repeatingFunc syntax error when using Chrome's console when I use just the variable name.

Comment: That sounds completely unrelated to your question. It sounds like a syntax error in whatever code you are trying (and not showing here), and not like the general behavior of the chrome console. Here is your [desired behavior, on my chrome console](https://i.imgur.com/JZRdJpy.png).

Comment: @ASDFGerte I'm not entering the variable into the console. I'm using it in a script (an editor in an html page). I'm copying the results to the console using `console.log(eval(editor.getText()))`, where `editor.getText()` is the JS code that contains the variable.

Comment: I think to solve your issue, more information about what you are actually trying to achieve would be useful.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I added an example of a simple JS editor that I'd like to be somehow parsed in the console.